# How to access/use Room DB (Android, Kotlin, MVVM) in background IntentService?

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, android-room, smack

I'am building a chat app with Smack on Android.
The ChatManager and other Listeners are running in an IntentService (right now).
When I receive a message I want to store it in my room DB.

From this service I can't access my DB (ViewModelProvider for MVVM needs a e.g. a FragmentActivity) to look for a person or a chat and store the message.

**What can I use to implement a listener in the background for the XMPP/Smack part and also be able to access the DB.**

I'm open to any idea and suggestions.

Comment: Since you are not in a View anyway, couldn't you just access the database directly and use your dao's to insert the data?

Comment: That might work, but would be against the MVVM pattern, as far as I understand. The Repository should handle all DB transactions. It also would need to be lifecycle owner to observe updates from the Internetservice.

Comment: That depends on your definition of the repository, I would describe the database object which gives you access to the daos as the repository, since all the database logic is in there. Also the repository has nothing to do with the ViewModel since this is only used for views and utilizes the repository.